# vue.js eslint how to get rid of the warning : Could not find a declaration file for module

Tags: vue.js, eslint

unit testing a component, I have to import a mixin ( vue-howler)

```
import VueHowler from "vue-howler";
```

I am getting a warning on the import regarding the implicit any ...

```
[ts]
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-howler'. '/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/VUE.JS-cli-3/3-chocha-home-content/chocha/node_modules/vue-howler/dist/vue-howler.common.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/vue-howler` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-howler';`
```

How I can solve this warning ? there is no @types/vue-howler ) ?

here is the related package.json eslint block

```
package.json

....
 "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-console": 0
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
 ....
```

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using typescript. If no typings exist for that particular package, you'll need to create your own definition file:

Name it `vue-howlder.d.ts`. The contents should be:

```
declare module `vue-howler`
```

Make sure your `tsconfig` file can find this in wherever your typings directory is.

Comment: I am not using TS directly, only JS  ...  the project was generated via vue-cli, and I am testing a component with this mixin ...  Compiling and running the component doewx not war about ts ...  only test unit ... strange ...  so I don't have any tsconfig file ... this is what I am looking for  : adding necessary ts files and config ( I know about TS but never used..)